# Get positions of certain letters in a sentence

Tags: javascript

I am having a exercise for school, i have a input box where i can put 1 letter (expample 'a')and i need to get all the positions of all the 'a's in this sentence:

```
<p id="langezin">Minister Jet Bussemaker van Onderwijs, Cultuur en Wetenschap bracht maandag een bezoek aan SintLucas locatie Boxtel. Vanuit het Koning Willem College waren hierbij aanwezig: Cor van Gerven, Erwin Brouwer en de leerlingen Gezel schilder Rick van Hoof, Wesley Stolzenbach en de Gezel stukadoor Rick van der Werf. Doel van het bezoek van de minister was om de titel Meester, die de excellentie van iemands vakmanschap bestempelt, te bespreken en te kijken of deze binnen het mbo ingezet kan worden. Bijvoorbeeld bij een 'moderne' opleiding zoals Game art. </p>
<input type="button" value="Keer de zin om" onclick="keerZinOm();">
```

I need the positions of the letter i type in the text box put out in a alert and i have to put out how much the letter is in that sentence.
This is the code i have so far:

```
function getZin() {
        zin = $('#langezin').html();
    }

function zoekLetter() {
    var waarde = document.getElementById('tekst').value;
    var zin = getZin();
    var indices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < zin.length; i++) {
        if (zin[i] === waarde) indices.push(i);
    }
    alert(indices)
}
```

I need to do it in javascript except getting the value of #langezin

Comment: To get the occurrences of a letter in a string, you could split the string on that letter and count the splits. For example, splitting the string `"Hello World"` at the letter `L` using `count = str.split("l").length - 1` would give you 3. As for position, I'll let someone else tackle that.

Comment: But in my sentence there are more then 1'l' and it only will give the first one.

Comment: Also be consistent: `var waarde = $('#tekst').val();`

Comment: What specific result do you want/expect if you look for the letter "a" in your posted paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to get the number of occurrences is return the length of `indices[]`

```
function getZin() {
        zin = $('#langezin').html();
    }

function zoekLetter() {
    var waarde = document.getElementById('tekst').value;
    var zin = getZin();
    var indices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < zin.length; i++) {
        if (zin[i] === waarde) indices.push(i);
    }
    alert(indices + " " + indices.length)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some error in your code, see working snippet below:

```js
function getZin() {
    return $('#langezin').html(); // need 'return' statement
} // and don't forget include jquery library

function zoekLetter() {
    var waarde = document.getElementById('tekst').value;
    var zin = getZin();
    var indices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < zin.length; i++) {
        if (zin[i] === waarde) indices.push(i);
    }
    alert(indices);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="langezin">Minister Jet Bussemaker van Onderwijs, Cultuur en Wetenschap bracht maandag een bezoek aan SintLucas locatie Boxtel. Vanuit het Koning Willem College waren hierbij aanwezig: Cor van Gerven, Erwin Brouwer en de leerlingen Gezel schilder Rick van Hoof, Wesley Stolzenbach en de Gezel stukadoor Rick van der Werf. Doel van het bezoek van de minister was om de titel Meester, die de excellentie van iemands vakmanschap bestempelt, te bespreken en te kijken of deze binnen het mbo ingezet kan worden. Bijvoorbeeld bij een 'moderne' opleiding zoals Game art. </p>

<input id='tekst'/>
<input type="button" value="Keer de zin om" onclick="zoekLetter();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the zin in your function

```
function getZin() {  
  var zin = $('#langezin').html();  
  return zin;  
}
```

or just

```
var zin = $('#langezin').text();
```

then you need to do something like

```
var idx = 0,indices=[];
while (idx!=-1) {
  idx=zin.indexOf(waarde,idx); 
  if (idx!=-1) indices.push(idx);
}
```

By the way if you need to reverse the sentence:

```
var zin = $('#langezin').text();
var omgekeerd = zin.split().reverse().join();
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually shouldn't need to use jQuery here at all as your `keerZimOm()` function should be able to retrieve everything you need in vanilla Javascript.

If you wanted to retrieve each of the indices that a specific character or string occurs, you could simply adjust the function triggered by your button as follows :

```
<!-- This stores the character you are looking for -->
<input id='tekst' maxlength='1' />
<!-- This will call your keerZinOm() function when clicked -->
<input type="button" value="Keer de zin om" onclick="keerZinOm();">
<script>
  function keerZinOm() {
    // This will get the word you are looking for
    var waarde = document.getElementById('tekst').value;
    // This pulls your content
    var zin = document.getElementById('langezin').innerHTML;
    // Store your indices
    var indices = [];
    // Loop through and find if the character exists
    for (var i = 0; i < zin.length; i++) {
        if (zin[i] === waarde) {
          indices.push(i);
        }
    }
    // This will alert each of the indices where the letter occurs
    alert(indices);
}
</script>
```

Likewise, if you just needed to output the number of occurrences, simply use the `length` property of your array :

```
alert(indices.length);
```

You can see an example of this below along with an example of it in action :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="langezin">Minister Jet Bussemaker van Onderwijs, Cultuur en Wetenschap bracht maandag een bezoek aan SintLucas locatie Boxtel. Vanuit het Koning Willem College waren hierbij aanwezig: Cor van Gerven, Erwin Brouwer en de leerlingen Gezel schilder Rick van Hoof, Wesley Stolzenbach en de Gezel stukadoor Rick van der Werf. Doel van het bezoek van de minister was om de titel Meester, die de excellentie van iemands vakmanschap bestempelt, te bespreken en te kijken of deze binnen het mbo ingezet kan worden. Bijvoorbeeld bij een 'moderne' opleiding zoals Game art. </p> 
  <pre>Enter a letter to search for: </pre>
  <input id='tekst' maxlength='1' />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="Keer de zin om" onclick="keerZinOm();">
  <script>
    function keerZinOm() {
        var waarde = document.getElementById('tekst').value;
        var zin = document.getElementById('langezin').innerHTML;
        var indices = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < zin.length; i++) {
            if (zin[i] === waarde) {
              indices.push(i);
            }
        }
        alert(indices)
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do suppose that in this state the code alerts only an empty array, am I right? I do think that your `getZin()` function is incorrect, since there is no return statement and you are setting a variable which is out of `getZin()` function's scope.

This should be the proper `getZin()` function:

```
function getZin () {
    return $('#langezin').html();
}
```

You then also need to add a text box in which you will write your input (the letter you are searching for).

Here is a functional JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/odzd0hcm/2/

Answer (score -1):

First extract the letter and text. Then see how much parts you can split the text if you split by the letter.

```
var letter=$('input').val();
var txt=$('#langezin').text();
var count=txt.split(letter).length - 1;
```